# plugin architecture .net maf or mef

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, mef, maf

I am currently working in a **game platform application**. I want to be able to easily add new games to it, but the games should be comply with a particular contract :

- The games must have some *required methods*
- They must receive some *events provided by the main program*
- They must be able to *send some data back* to the program
- It would be wonderful if it is easy for external developers to make games for the platform, just by having knowledge of the interface

I read some questions like **MEF vs MAF**, and at first I would think that *MAF is better* for me, but I am not sure of that. Plus, I think I could even make some kind of homemade system like, compiling games as DLLs and retrieve them at runtime.

MAF seems good because of the *isolation*, but since I am not really working with little add-in, and as I read, *MAF is heavy and lacks speed*, I have many doubts of what I should use.

Should I try MAF, even if it can be slow, and hard to develop, and does it really suits to what I am doing ?

Comment: System.AddIn (MAF) should be considered only if isolation and/or versioning is necessary AND you only need to expose the host to the add-ins (this is the case with Visual Studio and MS Office both of which use System.AddIn as far as I know). Also note that you can have versioning by combining MEF with Autofac (http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4/).

Answer (score 4):

This probably won't be your complete answer, but I will chime in on MEF, which I do have experience with (I have no real experience with MAF). MEF has a lot of advantages that I think are appropriate for your needs.

MEF is lightweight and it's ridiculously easy to use. It provides a dependency injection.

The discovery stuff is very easy to use. Just create your catalogs and you're off and running.

MEF makes plugin architectures a real snap. I'm totally sold on it.

While MAF may provide isolation, you have to make stuff remotable to call across app domains and that's cumbersome. To keep unhandled exceptions from taking out your main app, you have to create the add-ins in their own processes which has its own limitations. For example if you want to share DLLs among your add-ins, they either need to be in the same directory as the shared DLLs or the shared DLLs need to be in the GAC.

Comment: +1 Also you need to be extremely careful if you decide to have shared dll because you will most likely lose the versioning feature of System.AddIn (MAF). Preferably only assemblies whose public members will never change (such as the ones in .NET framework) should be shared by the host and add-ins.